# How do I get more tenants?

Tags: pocket-clothier

I have very few tenants, but lots of spaces I could place them. Problem is, I don't have very many unlocked, and I am not quite sure how to unlock more of them.

How do I unlock more of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [Japanese wiki](http://wikiwiki.jp/kairopark/?%A5%A2%A5%D1%A5%EC%A5%EB%CD%CE%C9%CA%C5%B9) here.

I ran it through Google Translate, and got this list of tenants. I've replaced the names with the English ones for those that I know and tried to translate the requirements as best I can.

- Idea Room: "Employees create items in the Fall season" Store ranked in the top 500.
- Storeroom: "Increases your product inventory size"  Perhaps it's registering for the Space competition for the first time?
- Toilet: "Increases your cleanliness rating, rate at which you aquire medals, and purchase limit" I think this one is registering for the Cleanliness competition for the first time.
- Dumpling (Takoyaki) Stand: "Increases your purchase limit" Store ranked in the top 900.
- Crepe Stand: Ibid. Unknown requirements.  I *believe* this is for getting 3 star rapport with Ladies' Apparel, though.
- Nail Art (Salon?): Ibid. Rank a clean; perhaps get first place in the Cleanliness competition?
- Piercing (Store?): "Increases rate at which you aquire medals and purchase limit" Unknown requirements
- Fitness Gym: Ibid. 3 star rapport with Fine Shirts
- Glasses (Kiosk/boutique?): Ibid. 3 star rapport with Merry Madam
- Beauty Salon: Ibid. 3 star rapport with Best Men's Tailoring
- Bookstore: Ibid. Store ranked in the top 300
- T-shirt Factory: Ibid. (This translates roughly to "Splendid/brilliant International friendship rating 3." It sounds like it is referring to a specific maker.)